# How can I reuse code from the android sdk for XML Parsing

Tags: java, android, android-xmlpullparser

I want to parse a xml file with enumerated values that contain numbers. 
The KxmlParser from android seems to have a problem with that. I looked inside the code and it only takes letters and some other tokens, but no numbers.

So I copied the KxmlParser Implementation and changed that part everything worked fine. But to resolve the references I added a libcore-jar to the project. Now I get compile erros because I shouldn't use this library excepto for creating a core libray.

So here's my question: What is the best way to change android-specific code for my application and to resolve the references to libcore?

Comment: have you tried [android xml pull parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but if you need to do something crazy like that (I also did) and you are using maven, you could do something like this to shade the packages:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jarjar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jarjar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <includes>
                    <include>com.fasterxml:aalto-xml</include>
                    <include>commons-codec:commons-codec</include>
                    <include>javax.xml.stream:stax-api</include>
                    <include>org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api</include>
                    <include>com.cookies:app</include>
                </includes>
                <rules>
                    <!-- We want to used STAX but Android doesn't generally like us including javax packages -->
                    <rule>
                        <pattern>javax.xml.stream.**</pattern>
                        <result>com.cookies.internal.javax.xml.stream.@1</result>
                    </rule>
                    <!-- Android packages commons-codec < 1.4 and we want to make use of the Base64OutputStream to *decode* -->
                    <rule>
                        <pattern>org.apache.commons.codec.**</pattern>
                        <result>com.cookies.internal.org.apache.commons.codec.@1</result>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```